# Redirect with Session flash data not showing in blade

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, api

I have problem with success -> Result I can't see Result after Redirect Success

Home.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route ('imei') }}" style="margin-top:5%">
                @csrf
                <p><input type="text" style="padding: 15px 10px 10px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',arial,sans-serif; border: 1px solid #cecece; color: black;box-sizing: border-box; width: 50%; max-width: 500px;" name="imei" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50" placeholder="Write here IMEI or SN"></p>
                <select name="service" id="service" style="padding: 15px 10px 10px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',arial,sans-serif; border: 1px solid #cecece; color: black;box-sizing: border-box; width: 50%; max-width: 500px;">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">PLEASE CHOOSE CHECKER</option>
                    <optgroup label="iPHONE SERVICES">
                        <option value="0.01">1.10 - APPLE SOLD BY & COVERAGE &#x26A1;</option>
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
                <br /><br />
                <button onClick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled=true; this.value='Please Wait'; " type="submit" style="background-color: #2ABCA7; padding: 12px 45px; -ms-border-radius: 5px; -o-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #2ABCA7;-webkit-transition: .5s; transition: .5s; display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; width: 20%; max-width: 200px; color: #fff;">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </center>

        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

        @if (Session::has('success'))
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Swal.fire({
              position: 'center',
              icon: 'success',
              title: "{!! Session::get('success') !!}",
              showConfirmButton: false,
              timer: 2500
            })
        </script>
        @elseif (Session::has('error'))
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Swal.fire({
              position: 'center',
              icon: 'error',
              title: "{!! Session::get('error') !!}",
              showConfirmButton: false,
              timer: 2500
            })
        </script>
        @endif
    </body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
public function imeiSubmit()
{
    $format = "html"; // Display result in JSON or HTML format
    $imei = $_POST['imei']; // IMEI or SERIAL Number
    $apiKey ='veCwe-bzgzE-JP9NE-ZHEaS-PxFuq-rnmLz';
    $service = $_POST['service']; // Service ID

    $balanceUrl = 'https://alpha.imeicheck.com/api/php-api/balance?key='.$apiKey;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $balanceUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);

    $balance = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($balance == '{"balance":"0.00"}') {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'balance 0.00!');
    }

    if ($service != 'demo') {
        $service = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $service);
    }

    if (strlen($service) > 4 || $service > 250) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Service ID is Wrong!');
    }

    if (!filter_var($imei, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        if (strlen($imei) < "11" || strlen($imei) > "15") {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'IMEI or SN is Wrong!');
        }
    }

    $curl = curl_init ("https://alpha.imeicheck.com/api/php-api/create?format='.$format.'&key='.$apiKey.'&service='.$service.'&imei='.$imei");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', PHP_EOL.$result);
    // // echo PHP_EOL."<br/><br/>".PHP_EOL.$result; // Here the result is printed
}
```

I want after submit get result with sweet alert but not working how can put `$result` with redirect back the Success

so anyone have solve this problem please let me

because the Result not Display

or

another solution

And

Thanks

Comment: first you will have to see what you are getting after redirecting to blade file . in blade file use {{ dd(session()->all()) }}  to check session key is exist or not

Comment: @ArifulIslam Hello

  Check image please : https://i.ibb.co/xjJnn9W/first-1.png

Comment: no session key exist called success or error

Comment: @ArifulIslam  

Done Adding but the $result not write in blade

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Swal.fire({
              position: 'center',
              @if (Session::has('success'))
                  icon: 'success',
                  title: "{!! Session::get('success') !!}",
              @endif
              @if (Session::has('error'))
                   icon: 'error',
                   title: "{!! Session::get('error') !!}",
              @endif
              showConfirmButton: false,
              timer: 2500
            })
        </script>
```

OR you can use this in blade file

```
@dd(session()->all());
```

Comment: Hello

Check Image : https://i.ibb.co/xjJnn9W/first-1.png

Comment: Yes exactly Now the try this session()->result.

Comment: Hello

i get Result working : https://i.ibb.co/522CyXQ/testx.png

but your code Swal.fire not working i got this - > https://i.ibb.co/vDQp4HT/test3.png